# Ошибка: E2141 Declaration syntax error

Tags: c++

Помогите найти и устранить ошибку в функции.

> ошибка [C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(11): E2141 Declaration syntax error

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma hdrstop
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
int sum(int a)
{
    return a + a;
}

int main()
{
for (int x=1;x<=10;++x)
std::cout<<sqare(x)<<" ";
std::cout<<std::endl;    std::cout << sum(3, 5) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3):

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma hdrstop
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cmath.h> // или math.h или cmath , как там захочет компилятор.

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma argsused

int sum(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  for (int x=1;x<=10;++x) {
    std::cout<<sqrt(x)<<" ";
  }
  std::cout<<std::endl;
  std::cout << sum(3, 5) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

функции `sqare` нет. Имелось ввиду sqrt? А также `sum` судя по коду, должен быть все таки с двумя параметрами. Хотя не понятно

Answer (score 3):

Для функции sqrt() нужно подключить библиотеку math.h, функция sum(3, 5) передает два значения, хотя у вас объявлено только одно int sum(int a)

Answer (score 1):

```
//у вас две функции main()  
    //следует писать так
    ...
    int sum(int );
    int main(int argc[], char **argv){...}
    int sum(int a){
    return 2*a;
    }
```

Comment: Спосибо за ответ и хорошие примеры вы все мне очень помогли ато думал над етими функциями два дня все работает цель програми была в том чтобы добыть корень с чисел =1 и <10 и узнать их суму

Comment: @Prog так оказывается, нужно получить сумму корней для чисел от 1 до 10?

Comment: а зачем так все сложно??  
например sum не такая сложная для понимания операция, чтобы выносить ее в отдельную функцию.  
и conio помойму не нужна.

Comment: sum - нужно ведь начинающим на чем то тренироваться?
А вот conio...  Это видно потому что в институте/школе ещё не в курсе, что есть новый стандарт. А Билдер и не противится.